# struct copy in c where struct are elements

Tags: c, struct

Hi i have following situation

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    Name team[5];
    Sport sport[5];
} School;

where Name and Sport are also structs,

typedef struct
{
    char arry[20];
}Name;

typedef struct
{
        char arry[20];
        int tag;
}Sport;
```

then

```
School first_school, second_school;
```

I populate them individually, then at some point I do

```
first_school = second_school
```

But I step through code this line doesn't seem to work. How should I copy ?

Comment: The problem isn't in the code posted. Please provide a minimal example with how you use these structs.

Answer (score 2):

> But I step through code this line doesn't seem to work. How should I copy ?

It's entirely correct to copy struct like that

```
first_school = second_school; // valid
```

If it doesn't work as expected then the error is somewhere else. For example, you need to do `strcpy()` for string members.

Comment: 'you need to do strcpy for string members.' so i should take care of all the string elements separately. like copy them 1 by 1 using strcpy?

Comment: @vow that statement applies to the first struct initialisation. If the struct has any string member you need to use `strcpy` give it initial value.

Comment: @vow The char arrays inside the structs are copied when you assign one struct variable to another. To set the value of a char array you would typically use `strcpy`. For example: `strcpy(second_school.team[0].arry, "Cubs");` would "assign" the string `Cubs` to the first team of `second_school`.

Comment: If the string struct members are just arrays and not pointers, there is no particular reason why you need to use strcpy in this case. Assignment will work just fine. So this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Structures are values that can be assigned. They can contain arrays, which *by themselves* are not assignable, but being inside a `struct` makes it possible.

That code is fine, except you need to reverse the order of the declarations, since `School` references `Name` and `Sport` they must be declared first.

I tested it and it works just fine after reversing the declaration order, this prints `hello`:

```
int main(void) {
    School foo, bar;
    strcpy(bar.team[0].arry, "hello");
    foo = bar;
    printf("'%s'\n", foo.team[0].arry);
    return 0;
}
```

There is probably something else wrong with your initialization of the `second_shool`, or you're failing to verify that it worked.

Answer (score -2):

It will work for most members, but you have one that cannot be copied like that `arry`. You should copy one element at a time from the target to the destination instances.

Note that there are functions that take care of such copying like `memcpy()`. But you cannot copy an array by assignment like you do with an `int` or a `struct` actually.

Comment: You can actually use assignment just fine if the array is fixed-size and located inside a struct. This is not the cause of the problem here.